# JQuery to expand selection to full tag contents

Tags: jquery

I have some "tags" enlosed in double brakets within a text area like:

```
Hello {{name}}, welcome to {{place}}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that if I click anywhere within the double brackets of a tag that I can get it to expand the selection to include all of the text within the bracket and then be able to use that selection within JQuery.

In other words, if I just click anywhere within the tag {{name}} it will get me the full tag text "name" without needing to select the whole thing.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: Huh? And here's some more text since SO doesn't allow pithy replies.

Comment: Um, what are you trying to do?  What do you mean by "expand the selection to the full bracket"?  Does the string literally contain `"{{name}}"`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to be able to click anywhere within {{name}} (not have to select the whole thing) and get the full tag {{name}}.

Comment: Basically, if I clicked anywhere within {{name}}, I could be able to alert {{name}}.  These are tags that get replaced with values.  I'm hoping the user can click on anywhere on a given tag, and I can then get the tag name and send them to the page to edit the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared following fiddle, which selects your 'tag' when clicked inside.

http://jsfiddle.net/zD8tc/

Comment: Fantastic, this is what I was trying to do.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: In case it helps anyone I adjusted a few things from Michal's great solution.  You can now double click on a {{tag}} and it will select the whole tag and get the tag value.  http://jsfiddle.net/9DVcx/29/.  Sorry I didn't word my original question very well.